# how can i append a vector in a function recursion which return a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

here is my function to change a Decimal number to a binary number,and it seems like the last sentence have some problem. i know i can create a static vector to solve the problem,but i don't want to make it this way. how can i append a vector which is the return object of the recursion function?

```
vector<int> tenchangetwo(int num)
{
    int i = num/2;
    int j = num%2;
    if(i==0)return vector<int>{j};
    else return tenchangetwo(i).push_back(j);
}
```

> Line 6: could not convert 'tenchangetwo(int)().std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back >(j)' from 'void' to 'std::vector'

Comment: hint: what is the return type of `std::vector<T>::push_back` and what is the return type of your function?

Comment: Talk to your rubber duck in the bathtub (and compile the code) before getting silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to first declare a variable to be returned in the end.

```
vector<int> tenchangetwo(int num)
{
    vector<int> v;
    int i = num/2;
    int j = num%2;

    if(i > 0) v = tenchangetwo(i);

    v.push_back(j);
    return v;
}
```

This makes your function cleaner and working.